# Passport.js Ajax login and flash?

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js, passport-local, connect-flash

I'm new to the express and passport.js and I'm very confused about how to make a ajax login with the passport.js, with no re-loading pafe but with showing flash messges.

(I'm use connect-flash and express-session)

Here is my code

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next)=>{
passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect : '/admin',
    failureRedirect : '/login',
    failureFlash : true
})(req, res, next);
```

});

strategy:

```
module.exports = passport => {
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'login'
    },
    (login, password, done) => {
        //match user
        User.findOne({
            login : login
        })
            .then(user => {
                if(!user){
                    return done(null, false, {message : 'no user found'});
                }

                //match passwords
                bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch)=>{
                    if (err) throw err;
                    if (isMatch) {
                        return done(null, user);
                    } else {
                        return done(null, false, {message : 'password incorrect'});
                    }
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(...);

passport.deserializeUser(...);
});
```

};

and the client

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/login",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('.alert-danger').html(data);
    },
})
```